# Reversing a list in Python

Tags: python, list, reverse

```
def manualReverse(list):
    return list[::-1]

    def reverse(list):
        return list(reversed(list))   

list = [2,3,5,7,9]

print manualReverse(list)
print reverse(list)
```

I just started learning `Python`. Can anyone help me with the below questions?

1.How come `list[::-1]` returns the `reversed` list?

2.Why does the second function throw me `NameError: name 'reverse' is not defined`?

Comment: See [The Python Slice Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/509211) for the slice notation.

Comment: You indented the function too far; it is not defined at the global level, so `reverse` is a **local** name inside `manualReverse`. Un-indent it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Python Slice Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation)

Comment: Dedent your `def reverse` so it lines up with `def ManualReverse` - otherwise, you're defining a function *inside* a function.... indentation is important in Python

Comment: Don't name your variable `list`. That will override the builtin name `list`, and indeed will cause an error in your code above once you fix the indentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`[::-1]` is equivalent to `[::1]`, but instead of going left to right, the negative makes it go right to left. With a negative step of one, this simply returns all the elements in the opposite order. The whole syntax is called the [Python Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation?lq=1).

The reason why `'reverse' is not defined` is because you did not globally define it. It is a local name in the `manualReverse` function. You can un-indent the function so it is a global function.

```
def manualReverse(list):
    return list[::-1]

def reverse(list):
    return list(reversed(list))
```

---

By the way, it's never a good idea to name lists `list`. It will override the built-in type, including the function too, which you depend on ( `list(reversed(list))` )

Comment: `manualReverse` will also successfully reverse a tuple and return a tuple, but `reverse` as shown will return the reverse of a tuple as a list. Better `reverse` code would be (assuming the `list` arg is renamed to `seq`): `return type(seq)(reversed(seq))`.

Answer (score 2):

`list[::-1]` utilizes a slice notation and returns all the elements but in reversed order.
[Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation)
Here is a detailed explanation with examples - it will answer this and more similar questions.

Indentation of `def reverse(list)` makes it visible only inside `manualReverse(list)`.
If You unindent it will become visible globally.

Comment: The question is "How come list[::-1] returns me the reversed list". Your answer basically repeats it in a slightly different wording.

Comment: @interjay I am not sure what is expected as the answer for "how come". The direct answer would be "because it is defined like that"

Comment: `[::-1]` is not magic syntax to reverse a list. It is an instance of slice notation which is a more general concept, and a real answer would explain that and/or refer to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the builtin function reversed

```
>>> reversed(my_list)
```

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=reversed#reversed

Comment: My opinion is to use builtin functions every time it's possible.
It's more optimized, cleaner, more readable.
Using the [::-1] syntax is not the right way to reverse a list.
In the question, apart from indentation error, the reversed function is not used correctly

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion. But this post does not answer the question at all. The `reversed` function is used correctly in the question, except for the error in using `list` as both a variable name and a builtin.

Comment: @P.M. You are right but guy is obviously trying to learn something here.